# ignore ios8 code in xcode 5 compilation

Tags: xcode, conditional-compilation

I've got a team working on some IOS code.  One developer (me) has Xcode6-beta with a few lines of IOS8 specific code.  When another developer with Xcode5 builds it for IOS7, compilation fails, because the IOS8 SDK doesn't exist for him.

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0){
    // ios8 code
} else {
    // ios7 and less way
}
```

Is there a way to ignore the IOS8 code in Xcode compilation based on the SDK or Xcode version, such that it compiles?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can do this using directives:

```
#ifdef __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED
// target is iOS
    #if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED < 80000
    // target is lower than iOS 8.0
    #else
    // target is at least iOS 8.0
    #endif
#endif
```

This is similar to commenting out unneeded lines of code but automatically. Compiller does not include everything which is stored 8.0-specific part of the if-statement.

Answer (score 1):

This [link](http://www.raywenderlich.com/42591/supporting-multiple-ios-versions-and-devices) is great. But in short ask the object if a certain method `respondsToSelector:`

```
if ([self.<object_name> respondsToSelector:@selector(<method_in_question>)]) {
    [self.<object_name> <method_in_question>];
}
```

This is much more dynamic than checking the actual OS version. Good luck!

Comment: This is runtime solution, my solution is working at compile-time. IF there is no support for the method, 100%, why should we check it at runtime and waste resources?

Comment: 1) I couldn't get yours to work in the time I had 
2) I don't enjoy dealing with low level code. 
3) 1 check, or 2 or 3, isn't going to slow down the app and waste resources enough to really matter, and this was much easier.

Comment: I agree with you, but if you do this check multiple times it may decrease performance. I considered that particular case that was mentioned by the asker, and I got the idea that in production version they will not need any version-dependent code. So I have chosen low-level solution for this. But your solution is more for multi-version support.

Comment: True, the check could decrease performance if performed multiple times. In my particular case, it won't be. That is the one other downside of your solution: it requires version upkeep. While it may be more efficient at compile time, it requires additional programmer overhead, which is can be less desirable than faster compile time and possibly saving some checks at runtime. Next time, if you know both solutions, I'd post them both.