# Skip/ignore method in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

How can I skip a complete method in iOS? I know how to test for the iOS version *inside* a method, but not how to completely ignore a method.

Concrete example: iOS8 added self sizing table view cells, and the methods `heightForRowAtIndexPath:` and `estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:` are no longer required. But I do need them for iOS7. Now when I step through the code in iOS8, both methods are called, even though they are no longer needed.

Comment: You could use a conditional. (`#if` - `#else` - `#endif`). That way it would be decided at compile time if certain lines of code will be executed or not.

Comment: Of course, but what would I test for?

Comment: @Koen This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24268070/ignore-ios8-code-in-xcode-5-compilation

Comment: Well, you could have two different implementations of the delegate class, and select which one you create.

Comment: Sounds like your best option is to do the run-time check as the first line of the method and skip the entire body when you don't need it.

Comment: @PhillipMills: I thought of that, but both methods require a return value. Maybe I could just return the value of the super in iOS8?

Comment: When responding to a delegate protocol method from an arbitrary class does not necessarily have `[super yourMethodCallHere]` defined.

Comment: This question is a duplicate of: [How to only override a method depending on the runtime system iOS version?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26022113/how-to-override-a-method-only-if-ios-version-earlier-thn-8)

Comment: In that thread (in which I apparently participated), the `respondsToSelector` solution is the accepted answer. Here I read that it may not be ideal, and using a separate `delegate` is a better solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provide a different delegate based on iOS version. This allows you to encapsulate your code in meaningfully-named blocks (your interface will indicate that it's iOS7) and you won't be doing any trickery with `respondsToSelector` that could break subclasses of your class that actually *do* want to use those methods.

```
@interface MyTableViewDelegate : NSObject <UITableViewDelegate>
@end

@interface MyTableViewDelegateiOS7 : MyTableViewDelegate
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
@end

@implementation YourClass : .. <..>
// ..
- (void)loadView {
  [super loadView];
  if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:@"8.0" options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending) {
    self.tableView.delegate = [[MyTableViewDelegate alloc] init];
  } else {
    self.tableView.delegate = [[MyTableViewDelegateiOS7 alloc] init];
  }
}
@end
```

Comment: `MyTableViewController` is the delegate (and datasouerce) for the `UITableView`. If I understand it correctly, your answer suggests that another class acts as the delegate?

Comment: That's correct. Two other classes, in fact, though the iOS7 one extends from the other, so you won't be duplicating code, just adding the iOS7 functionality where needed.

Comment: Alright, I get it. I think I've read about using a separate delegate/datasource class before, but never saw the need for it. This may just be the case.

Comment: @Koen, indeed it is always better to have an own class for datasource/delegate, as this improves the reusability and empowers to code according to the Single Responsible Principle. Also have a look at last years WWDC video «Advances in UICollectionViews» or similar. It is shown clearly that apple uses this approach too.

Comment: [Advanced User Interfaces with Collection Views](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/)

Comment: I'm trying to implement this approach, but getting crashes, see my follow up question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28011737/refactoring-uitableview-delegates-for-ios7-and-ios8

Answer (score 5):

You have a `UITableViewDelegate` set as the delegate for a `UITableView` and you want to present different delegate methods to different versions of iOS.

`UITableView` will call `[delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:)]` before calling `[delegate tableView:self heightForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]`.

This calls for a custom [`-respondsToSelector:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/respondsToSelector:). In your `UITableViewDelegate` class add this method.

```
- (BOOL)respondsToSelector:(SEL)aSelector
{
    // If this device is running iOS 8 or greater.
    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:@"8.0" options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending) {
        if (aSelector == @selector(tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:))
            return NO;

        if (aSelector == @selector(tableView:estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:))
            return NO;
    }

    return [super respondsToSelector:aSelector];
}
```

---

***UPDATE: I fixed the delegate method names. DUH!***

Comment: @vikingosegundo yeah, I meant `-tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` and `-tableView:estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:`. Sorry about that.

Comment: This is a clever solution!  Not 100% sure that it will work (getting a little "double double toil and trouble" there), but it's certainly worth considering.